# change source in list guesser - React-admin

Tags: symfony, react-admin

I'm using React Admin, and I have this result :

[image: screenshot]

As you can see, React admin displays `/media_objects/:id`.

I would like to display the title instead of the id.

Here is my code :

```
export const MediaAreasList = props => (
    <ListGuesser {...props}>
        <FieldGuesser label={labelLabel} source="label" />
        <FieldGuesser source="title" label={titleLabel} />
        <FieldGuesser source="description" />
        <FieldGuesser source="mediaObjects" label={mediaObjectsLabel} />
    </ListGuesser>
);
```

Is there a way to display titles instead of id ?

I didn't find anything in the doc

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use ListGuesser in production https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Tutorial.html

> you’ll have to replace the ListGuesser component in the users
> resource by a custom React component. Fortunately, ListGuesser dumps
> the code of the list it has guessed to the console

In your case `FieldGuesser` for `mediaObjects` should be replaced with `ReferenceManyField` component:

```
<ReferenceManyField label={mediaObjectsLabel} reference="mediaObjects" target="...">
  <SingleFieldList>
    <ChipField source="title" />
  </SingleFieldList>
</ReferenceManyField>
```

docs: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/ReferenceManyField.html